# How to use MSBUILD to automate culture-specific satellite assemblies with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, localization, visual-studio-2017, satellite-assembly

I am trying to build satellite assemblies for localized resources using the MSBUILD configuration here:

[Automated build of Satellite Assemblies in Visual Studio with MSBUILD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pedram/2007/08/04/automated-build-of-satellite-assemblies-in-visual-studio-with-msbuild/)

However, the satellite assemblies are not loading when changing the culture.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Visual Studio 2017 configuration:

[image: strings resx files]

**strings.resx** and **strings.de.resx** have only one string defined, String1, which is either "My English String" or "My German String."

I have the following post build event:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild" "$(SolutionDir)\TestLocalization\build.msbuild" /v:d /property:destination="$(TargetDir)
```

**build.msbuild**:

```
<!-- Resource files -->
<ItemGroup>
  <Res Include = "strings.de.resx">
    <Culture>de</Culture>
  </Res>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Main">
  <Message Text="$(destination)"/>
  <CallTarget Targets="CompileResources" />
  <CallTarget Targets="BuildSatelliteAssemblies" />
  <CallTarget Targets="CopyToFolder" Condition="$(destination)!=''"/>
  <CallTarget Targets="CleanUp" />
</Target>

<!-- Generate .resource file from .resx -->
<Target Name="CompileResources">
  <GenerateResource Sources="@(Res)" PublicClass="true" >
    <Output ItemName="Resources" TaskParameter="OutputResources"/>
  </GenerateResource>
</Target>

<!-- Create a satellite assembly for each culture -->
<Target Name="BuildSatelliteAssemblies" DependsOnTargets="CompileResources">
  <MakeDir Directories="%(Res.Culture)"/>

  <AL OutputAssembly="%(Culture)\TestLocalization.resources.dll"
      Version="1.0.0.0"
      Culture="%(Culture)"
      EmbedResources="@(Resources)"/>
</Target>

<!-- copy from the resources folder at the solution level to 
     the destination folder passed in as a property to the msbuild -->
<Target Name="CopyToFolder" DependsOnTargets="BuildSatelliteAssemblies">
  <MakeDir Directories="$(destination)\%(Res.Culture)"/>
  <CreateItem Include="%(Res.Culture)\*.dll" AdditionalMetadata="Culture=%(Res.Culture)">
    <Output ItemName="SatelliteAssemblies" TaskParameter="Include"/>
  </CreateItem>
  <Copy DestinationFolder="$(destination)%(Culture)"
        SourceFiles="@(SatelliteAssemblies)" />
</Target>

<!-- remove temporary files and folders-->
<Target Name="CleanUp">
  <Delete Files="@(Resources)"/>
  <RemoveDir Directories="%(Res.Culture)" />
</Target>
```

**Form1.cs**:

```
namespace TestLocalization
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
            Console.WriteLine(strings.String1);
            label1.Text = strings.String1;
        }
    }
}
```

I see that the resource DLL **bin\Debug\de\TestLocalization.resources.dll** is generated, but the corresponding German string is not loaded when the program is run.  If I remove the MSBUILD post build event and just use embedded resources for both **strings.resx** and **strings.de.resx**, the German string gets loaded properly.

[image: TestLocalization.resources.dll]

Comment: Creating your own localization scheme is never not a mistake.  Use the built-in support for it.  In the designer change the Language property of the form to de-DE and type the German flavor of the string.  That creates a .resx file for the form, everything else is automagic.

Comment: What if you would like to add or modify strings/languages without having to rebuild?

Comment: How do custom build tasks in the project file provide that feature?

Comment: I'd have to agree with Hans here. We never have to do special build handling for language things like this above. Just let visual studio and msbuild handle it.

Comment: You're correct; it does not solve that problem.  I was working under the assumption that satellite assemblies for localized resources needed to be "seeded" or created separately from the built-in mechanism in order for them not to be embedded in the main assembly.  I see this to be incorrect now.  (I'm a first time .NET localizer).  Thanks.